# MSBuild edit XML .proj file during the build, delete a node

Tags: xml, msbuild

I have a msbuild project file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" ...">
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="1.csproj">
      <Project>{a1}</Project>
      <Name>Some info1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="2.csproj">
      <Project>{a2}</Project>
      <Name>some info2</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup
```

I need to delete second node `ProjectReference` from 'ItemGroup, like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" ...">
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="1.csproj">
      <Project>{a1}</Project>
      <Name>Some info1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup
```

How to do that? I've tried this:

```
<TransformXml Source="$(ProjectPath)"
  Transform="%(ProjectReference.Identity)"
  Destination="$(ProjectPath)"
  Condition=" '@(ProjectReference.Identity)'='1.csproj'" />
```

But it didnt work. Also I tried this:

```
<XmlUpdate
      XmlFileName="$(ProjectPath)"
      XPath="//Project/ItemGroup/ProjectReference[@Include='%(ProjectReference.Identity)']"
      Delete="true"
      Condition=" '@(ProjectReference.Identity)'='1.csproj'"/>
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit for what kind of scenario you're trying to implement ? There might be easier way to achieve the result.

If you're trying to modify your build process on-the-fly - it won't work because once you starting your build - all scripts are parsed and form in-memory model - so even if you'll change the original file - that doesn't affect the build flow.

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak Hi, I'm not trying to affect current build flow, I just need to modify some `*.*proj`  files by removing some nodes, so next build will be affected. I need to delete some items in ItemGroup.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from high-level perspective ? is this because you want to include different references on every build or you want to use msbuild as your scripting language and perform some unrelated tasks over other XML files, which are by coincidence msbuild files?
If this is for conditional build - it'd be easier to put Condition attribute on your project references item group so they will participate in the build only when condition is true (e.g. in some special configuration you want to add debuggable dll or one with special logging)